# Creating a .pcap file in native code in Android then retrieving it

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, native, pcap

I have an app that uses native code to generate a .pcap file (amongst other things). The idea is that while running the program, the pcap file is created and I can later retrieve it by say plugging in the phone into my laptop and then access it.

I use fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() in my native code to create the .pcap file. My question is, how should I specify the filename and filepath? For example, when I run it on windows, I just use "test.pcap" and it generates it in the same folder, but how does this work on android? As I mentioned before, the file is created down in native level.

Answer (score 0):

Native or not, the directory structure should be the same.
You can create a directory in */flash* called *pcap*. But check it exists first, as it can be */nand*. Use */sdcard* if you want to write in the SD card.

After that you can use, say, */flash/pcap/test.pcap* as path for the file. The file would be created in the internal flash memory.

Comment: so if I want to write to the SDcard I would simply use "/sdcard/test.pcap" as path. About opening the file later, is the SD card simply the storage when I plug the phone into my laptop and open the external storage?

Comment: Not sure about that as when I plug mine is /flash what I see from the laptop. I don't have an SD card right now but my guess is that in your laptop you would see both SD card and internal flash memory.